# Rails: Send request back to router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on an app with some CMS-functionality where the client can match arbitrary paths for their articles.

Now, I would like to use route globbing to match ANY html request and then check in the controller if I have some article to show. If no article is present, I want to send the request back into the route resolution flow, to search for other potential matches.

I imagine there should be an exception for just that, but I can't figure it out. It's not `RoutingError`.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file: `config/routes.rb` runs top-to-bottom when defining your application routes. All you need to do is define a catch-all at the top of this file.

I'd also recommend you look into using some sort of [`Constraint`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) (so you can also cache the result). For example, your solution may look something like:

```
 # config/routes.rb
 get '*', to: 'Article#show', constraints: ArticleConstraint.new

 # lib/article_constraint.rb
 class ArticleConstraint
   def matches?
     # Really trivial example... You could make this better, e.g. use cacheing!
     Article.exists?(name: request.path)
   end
 end
```

Comment: This is what I am already doing, but I would like to avoid the separate constraint class and factor it into the controller so I throw an exception like `RoutingError`, that gets the Rails router to continue the search. This is useful when you have multiple catch all controllers.

Comment: `multiple catch all controllers`  -- This sounds like a bad idea to me... Why not just namespace the routes, e.g. `/articles/custom-path-1`, `/users/custom-path-2`?

Comment: This would also avoid the issue of conflicts between different controllers, and improve application performance

Comment: Tom Lord, I fully agree. Unfortunately, clients don't think of it that way. Whatever Mr. Seo consultant says are words of God.